# get notifications for facebook invite friends in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

In my iPhone app I am sending apprequests to facebook friends using facebook graph api.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = 
            [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check this app"], @"message",
                   @"TEST",@"title",
                   friendsIDs,@"to",
                    nil];


[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

I am getting notifications in facebook appcenter not in globe icon. How can I get notifications in globe icon? 
Please help!!!

Comment: Sorry. I mean how to get notifications for apprequest.

Comment: Have you resolved that issue? I have the same right now.